# Notepad++ Find & Replace WildCard

Tags: notepad++

I have read plenty on trying to find out how to replace with Notepad++ but I just seem to end up nowhere.

Here's an example Juniper Config which I will be changing into another language:

```
set policy id 3016 from "CSA" to "Untrust"  "1.1.1.1/32" "2.2.2.2/32" "SSH" permit log 
set policy id 3016
set dst-address "3.3.3.3/32"
exit
!    
set policy id 3053 name "Footprints" from "Untrust" to "CSA"  "Blocked Addresses" "Any" "ANY" deny log 
set policy id 3053
exit
```

Now I want to change this into Fortinet Language, but for me to begin this process I need it to look for certain variables. The few bits I need to change is:

```
set policy id 3016 from "CSA" to "Untrust"  "1.1.1.1/32" "2.2.2.2/32" "SSH" permit log 
set policy id 3016
set dst-address "3.3.3.3/32"
exit
!    
set policy id 3053 name "Footprints" from "Untrust" to "CSA"  "Blocked Addresses" "Any" "ANY" deny log 
set policy id 3053
exit
```

to

```
edit 0
    set srcintf "CSA"
    set dstintf "Untrust"
    set srcaddr "1.1.1.1/32"
    set dstaddr "2.2.2.2/32" "3.3.3.3/32"
    set action accept
    set schedule "always"
    set service "SSH"
    set fsso disable
    set nat enable
next
edit 0
    set name "Footprints"
    set srcintf "Untrust"
    set dstintf "CSA"
    set srcaddr "Blocked Addresses"
    set dstaddr "all"
    set action accept
    set schedule "always"
    set service "ALL"
    set fsso disable
    set nat enable
next
```

so I used the following to try and get me going first:

Find `(set policy id (.+))` and replace with `edit 0` - This seems to highlight everything and leave me with empty configuration with just edit 0 left.

Then I tried find `(set policy id *)` and replace with `edit 0` - This leaves me with everthing but changes it so it looks like the below: (Basically insets 0 before XXXX

```
edit 03016 from "CSA" to "Untrust" "1.1.1.1/32" "2.2.2.2/32" "SSH" permit log set policy id 3016 set dst-address "3.3.3.3/32" exit
```

Any help would be massively appreciated as this could save me hours!!!!

Comment: If I well understand you want to add linebreaks after `set policy id X`, `from X`  and `to X`? Please, [edit your question](https://superuser.com/q/1499596/763386) and add exact expected result for the few lines you gave as example. Especially, what to do with lines that contain only `set policy id 3016` without `from` or `to.`

Comment: @Toto I have editted that now, hopefully you can see what the Fortinet language looks like, I am not sure how achievable it is to get as close as possible.

Comment: @Toto Further to note the below lines don't matter too much, these just need adding:
    **set action accept**
    **set schedule "always"**
    **set fsso disable**
    **set nat enable**

Answer (score 1):

#### IMHO you should write a script in your favorite scripting language.

But if you really want to do this job with Ntepad++, here is a regex solution. As you can see the regex and the replacement is a bit complex and require good knowledge to be maintained.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `set policy id \d+ (?:(?:(?!exit).)*?name (".+?"))?(?:(?!exit).)*?from (".+?")(?:(?!exit).)*?to (".+?")(?:(?!exit).)*?("\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3}/\d+"|"[\w ]+") ("\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3}/\d+"|"[\w ]+") (".+?")(?:(?:(?!exit).)*?set dst-address (".+?"))?(?:(?!exit).)+?exit`
- Replace with: `edit 0\n\t(?1set name $1\n\t:)set srcintf $2\n\tset dstintf $3\n\tset srcaddr $4\n\tset dstaddr $5(?7 $7:)\n\tset action accept\n\tset schedule "always"\n\tset service $6\n\tset fsso disable\n\tset nat enable\nnext`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **CHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>
- <kbd>Find All in Current Document</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
set policy id \d+                           # literally and digits for id
(?:                                         # non capture group
    (?:(?!exit).)*?                         # 0 or more any character but not the word "exit"
    name (".+?")                            # name is captured in group 1
)?                                          # end group, optional
(?:(?!exit).)*?                             # 0 or more any character but not the word "exit"
from (".+?")                                # from is captured in group 2
(?:(?!exit).)*?                             # 0 or more any character but not the word "exit"
to (".+?")                                  # to is captured in group 3
(?:(?!exit).)*?                             # 0 or more any character but not the word "exit"
("\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3}/\d+"|"[\w ]+")    # group 4, src IP or literal like "Blocked Addresses"
("\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3}/\d+"|"[\w ]+")    # group 5, dst IP or literal like "Any"
(".+?")                                     # group 6, service
(?:                                         # non capture group
    (?:(?!exit).)*?                         # 0 or more any character but not the word "exit"
    set dst-address                         # literally
    (".+?")                                 # group 7, 1 or more any character, not greedy
)?                                          # end group, optional
(?:(?!exit).)*?                             # 0 or more any character but not the word "exit"
exit                                        # literally
```

**Replacement:**

```
edit 0\n\t                      # edit 0 followed by linefeed and tabulation
(?1                             # if group 1 exists, (name)
    set name $1\n\t               # print the name (group 1)
    :                           # else
                                  # nothing
)                               # end if
set srcintf $2\n\t              # and so on ...
set dstintf $3\n\t
set srcaddr $4\n\t
set dstaddr $5
(?7 $7:)\n\t
set action accept\n\t
set schedule "always"\n\t
set service $6\n\t
set fsso disable\n\t
set nat enable\n
next
```

**Screen capture (before):**

[image]

**Screen capture (after):**

[image]

You'll find complete explanation [here](https://regex101.com/r/NmYUaO/1)